# How do you pass multiple arguments to nested route paths in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes, link-to

I am new to Rails and normally set up a `link_to` helper for a normal unnested route like so:

```
link_to "Delete", article_path(article.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}
```

However I am learning about nested routes and it seems I need to provide the path with two arguments for example:

```
link_to "(Delete)", article_comments_path(comment.article_id, comment.id), method: :delete, data:{comfirm: 'Are you sure?'}
```

However this does not seem to  work. I have seen that you can format the `link_to` like this:

```
link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

But this seems confusing to me as there is no path defined and the values necessary for the path arn't directly specified either.

Is it possible to format a nested `link_to` path like the unnested one above or does it need to be formatted as shown in the third example? If so could someone try to explain how this array format is translated into a url for Rails to execute?

Thanks

Route:

article_comment_path - DELETE - /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format) -  comments#destroy

Comment: Can you post your rake routes output? Also i doubt your 3rd link_to will work, i think it'll be polymorphic_path([comment.article, comment])

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your route would be something like `articles/:article_id/comments/:id` so you can do:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", article_comments_path(article_id: comment.article_id, id: comment.id), method: :delete, data:{comfirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

And your 3rd link should be

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', polymorphic_path(comment.article, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

For details check [**`Polymorphic routes`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html)

**Update**

You just need to pass locals to your partial like:

```
<%= render "comment", locals: {article: comment.article, comment: comment} %>
```

and then use

```
<%= link_to "Delete", article_comments_path(article.id,comment.id), method: :delete, data:{comfirm: 'Are you sure?'}%>
```

Comment: Thanks, the link_to is in a partial with name _comment. Ive added the route into the description. The third link_to does seem to work for me.

Comment: @Cu1ture updated my answer. You just need to pass proper locals to the partial and that 3rd link, not sure but i think rails is calling polymorphic path by default on it