# Rails 5 incorrect URL in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my OrganizationsController in have this:

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_login

  def show
    @organization = current_user.organizations.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

And in show.html.erb

```
<% @organization.repositories.each do |repository| %>
  <%= link_to repository.name, organization_repository_path(repository) %>
<% end %>
```

Params:

```
Parameters <ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"organizations", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"3"} permitted: false>
```

routes:

```
URI pattern:
organization_repository GET /organizations/:organization_id/repositories/:id(.:format)
```

Link_to generates this URL:

```
/organizations/126/repositories/3
```

Whereas the organization_id is 3 and repository_id is 126 so the URL should rather be:

```
/organizations/3/repositories/126
```

How to generate proper URL?

```
/organizations/3/repositories/126
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269232/how-do-you-pass-multiple-arguments-to-nested-route-paths-in-rails

Comment: You are absolutely brilliant! I've been fighting with this the WHOLE DAY!  Thank you so much:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you pass multiple arguments to nested route paths in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269232/how-do-you-pass-multiple-arguments-to-nested-route-paths-in-rails)